# How to centre an HTML snippet within the browser?

Tags: html, css

An app I'm working on receives HTML from an API and needs to add some simple formatting to it for rendering in a browser. The content received is typically just an `<img>` wrapped in an `<a>` - very simple.

Example HTML received:

```
<a href="http://www.blah.com"><img src="http://www.blah.com/image.gif"></a>
```

I need to format that received HTML using inline styles (in tags I add around it) that will centre the content within the browser's document area, both horizontally and vertically. I cannot alter the snippet itself, so I need to build an HTML container that will correctly centre whatever snippet is provided.

Here's where I'm at:

```
<html>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;  ">
<div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">

<!-- Snippet -->
<a href="http....."><img src="http...." width="300" height="50" /></a>

</div></body>
</html>
```

I couldn't get the page to do what I needed with styles, so to clarify this what I need here is a (working) solution implemented using tables. I'd much prefer to do it with styles.

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;  ">
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<center>

<!-- snippet  -->
<a href="http..."><img border="0" alt="" src="http..." width="300" height="500" /></a>

</center>
</td>
</tr>
<table>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you put here how your html that will receve the new html? And how you are creating the html and the exemple of the returned html?

Comment: -1: "This question does not show any research effort" - what have you tried?

Comment: I thought the question was pretty clear - it's a very simple problem - but I've added more detail to clarify it, and what I've tried.

Comment: What do you know about the HTML you receive and what surrounds it? Are there any fixed widths, for example?

Comment: @Nix The HTML is a snippet (i.e. no HTML or BODY tags etc) but other than that it will vary in format. Not sure what you mean by "are there any fixed widths".

Comment: +0 @OllieC the question **was** pretty clear; but it showed no research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you know the width of the image, you may be able to position it absolutely, and center it that way.

```
img { /* Assuming a size of 300 by 500, as in your example */
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-250px 0 0 -150px;  }
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/W4cPw/3/

---

**UPDATE**

In the case where you don't know the content or the surrounding markup at all, the only way to do this (without Javascript hacks) is with tables (*gasp!*).

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/500" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
html, body, table {
    width:100%;
    height:100%; }

td {
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center; }
```

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/W4cPw/4/

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work. As I said in the question the example given is typical, but the HTML in the snippet varies. The content may be an image, it may be some text in a div, it could be something else entirely - the API I'm using delivers content of many types, and they may change, however they are always simple HTML snippets, and will not have any positioning styling in them.